# Render Serialized data in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm new to django and web development and wanna know how to render html with serialized data which i use for my api's
here's my files:

Views.py

```
class IngredientsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get','post','patch','delete','options','head']
    permission_classes = [isAdminOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Ingredients.objects.all()
    

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ['POST','PATCH','delete']:
            return IngredientCreateSerializer
        return IngredientSerializer
```

Models.py

```
class Ingredients (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    inventory = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='products')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

Serializer.py

```
class IngredientSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ['id','title','unit_price','description','collection']

class IngredientCreateSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta :
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ['id','title','slug','unit_price','description','collection','inventory']
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # featured_ingredient = IngredientSerializer()
    class Meta :
        model = Collection
        fields = ['id','title','featured_ingredient']
```

I want to render a html file and pass my Ingredient model data to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.